# Generate random numbers with less probabilities of bigger numbers

Tags: javascript, random

I want to implement a random number generator which lets me set the maximum number I want but also lets me tweak the probabilities to make it harder to get bigger number.

Using this would allocate the same probabilities to any value in the range of 100.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
```

How can I make numbers get progressively harder to appear as the number gets closer to the limit (100)?

Comment: And thus calculus was reborn once again.

Comment: How much progressively harder? How many more 0's do you expect than 99s? Also, btw here you range is actualy 0 to 99. You will never get 100. if you want to go from 0 to 100, multiple by 101. If you want to go from 1 to 100, multiply by 100 and add 1 (or use ceiling instead of floor).

Comment: I've always needed something like this! Great question! Oh, by the way, I don't think your code can actually generate the number 100. Try using 101, since the range of Math.random() is 0 to 1, but 1 in exclusive (It will never appear).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Square the result of `Math.random`:

```
var result = Math.random();
result = result * result;
result *= 100;
result = Math.floor(result);
```

You can adjust the curve by adjusting the exponent. Here's a few graphs of different exponents:

[image: The larger exponents are steeper.]

If you're going to use a non-integer exponent, you'll need to use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a mathematically function that has curve giving you the required probability weighting. For example, you could 'square' your number:

[image]

```
var num = Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.random()*10), 2);
```

The above generates a random number between 1-10 then squares it to give a random number between 1-100, but weighted towards lower numbers.

You can further increase the weighting by using  higher power.

Answer (score -1):

Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.random()*10), 2);

Or something similar.