# javascript get random number: lower probability to get higher number in the interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Ok, so I have very big array of numbers in javascript:

```
[1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, ..., 1.99, 2, ..., 9.98, 9.99, ..., 299.99, 300]
```

And what I need is to get one of them using random segment. So basically I need random number but the catch is that I need to get random using the lottery style. So the chance to get "1" will be 30 000 (very hight) and the chance to get 1.01 will be 29 999. But the chance to get 300 will be very low according of all numbers in this array.

I hope you will understand the problem and will help me to solve this. As I have mentioned before, this have to be made 100% randomly and I have no idea how to make it..

The solution I had so far:

I was trying to expanse the array by adding multiple same numbers and lower the count of it by each step. So I have added `30000` units of `1` and `29999` units of `1.01` ... and 2 units of 299.99 and one unit of 300. But the array got very large and I came here to find better solution.

Also I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758064/5786106
and it seems to be the answer to me but I don't know how to use it with the decimal system (0.01, 0.02, ... 0.99)

`var num = Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.random()*10), 2);`

Comment: so make the correct title, thats a big reason why youre getting down voted right now

Comment: i need a unicorn, and i have no idea how to get one. what have you tried? what have you looked into? show us some effort, we're not a code writing machine that does your projects/hw for you.

Comment: I can't even format correct title because I don't know excatly what I need. And yes, I will write what I have tried till now.

Comment: @DaumantasKarpavicius if you don't know what you need, how can you expect someone to help you? I think you need to read on random numbers distribution. Perhaps look into other solutions, such as https://github.com/ckknight/random-js and see. There is no such thing as 100% random, there's always some degree of bias.

Comment: I think Daumantas knows what he needs but didn't express it very well. What he actually wants is to pick randomly from his array but to weight each element by (1 + distance-from-end). I agree he could have spent more effort, but his proposed solution is actually reasonable if space and time limitations didn't exist.

Comment: @Eihwaz, no, there doesn't have to be bias: Math.random() is not biased, unless you're talking about the differences between pseudorandomness and true randomness, which isn't at all what the questioner is interested in.

Comment: @MichaelSaunders I just assumed that if OP is talking about 100% random he means the real thing, and all we know about randomness is from our (humanity) observations, there is very little chance we got it 100% right with our formulas. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to make the very large array you propose, but to make it imaginary, without ever constructing that object in code.

How long will the imaginary array be? Well your array has (300 - 1) * 100 + 1 = 29,901 elements in it. Then there are (29,901 + 1) * (29,901 / 2) = 447,049,851 elements in the imaginary array. So the first step is to generate a random integer between 0 and 447,049,850:

```
var imaginaryIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 447049851);
```

The next step is to determine which real index in your original array corresponds to the imaginaryIndex in the imaginary array.

```
var indexFromEnd = 0;
while((indexFromEnd + 2) * ((indexFromEnd + 1) / 2) < imaginaryIndex)
    indexFromEnd++;
```

Finally, you need to calculate the value of the element in your array based on where it is in your array:

```
return 300 - (indexFromEnd * 0.01);
```

Now let's clean that up and put it in a nice, reusable function:

```
function triangularWeightedRandomSelect(myArray){
    var imaginaryIndex = 
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (myArray.length + 1) * myArray.length / 2);
    var indexFromEnd = 0;
    while((indexFromEnd + 2) * ((indexFromEnd + 1) / 2) < imaginaryIndex)
        indexFromEnd++;
    return myArray[myArray.length - 1 - indexFromEnd];
}
```

Comment: it seems like worked and worked well, but does it correct if it gives me high numbers often then lower ones? Because it should give 0-150 more often then 150-300. And 1-2 range should be generated much often then others: http://pastebin.com/r397YQcx

Comment: Yes, according to your requirement, the number should fall in the range 0-150 75% of the time and it should fall in the range 1-2 about 0.7% of the time, more than any other 100-element range. By the way, I realized that your array is 29900 elements long, not 30000, so there's a slight bug in my code that occasionally generates in the range 0-1. I'll fix at some point

Comment: Fixed the bug. # of elements is 29901